# Using destructuring how to receive parameters in a function with a default custom type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, destructuring

I have created a service to issue alerts using Mat-snackbar, I use destructuring to receive the variables in my functions, I require one of the variables to be of a specific type

```
export class NotificationsService {

  // MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top' | 'bottom'; this is the required type

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  alert({ message, buttonText = 'Ok', verticalPosition = 'top' }) {
    let alertConfig = {
      verticalPosition: verticalPosition,
    };
    this.snackBar.open(message, buttonText, alertConfig);
  }
}
```

The verticalPosition property is of type MatSnackBarVerticalPosition (it can be 'bottom' or 'top'), I don't know how to set the value of top or bottom by default because it tells me that there is an error since a string type cannot be transformed into MatSnackBarVerticalPosition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So take that you would like to achieve something like the following:

```js
let a = {
    aa: 123,
    bb:456,
    cc
};

const {aa, bb, cc = 'Top'}: {aa: number, bb: number, cc: string} = a;

console.log(cc); // Will log 'Top'
```

I think in your case, it could be the following:

```js
interface yourType {
  message: string,
  buttonText: string,
  verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition
}

alert({ message, buttonText = 'Ok', verticalPosition = 'top' }: yourType) {
    let alertConfig = {
      verticalPosition: verticalPosition,
    };
    this.snackBar.open(message, buttonText, alertConfig);
  }
```

Could you give this a try? :)

[Reference](https://flaviocopes.com/typescript-object-destructuring/)

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked for me, assign the default value to another variable that has the required type

```
verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top';

alert({ message, buttonText = 'Ok', verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition }) {
    let alertConfig = {
      verticalPosition: verticalPosition,
    };
    this.snackBar.open(message, buttonText, alertConfig);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about typing. You need to declare/assert type somewhere to make TypeScript happy, for example:

```
const alertConfig = {
    verticalPosition: verticalPosition as MatSnackBarVerticalPosition,
};
```

Comment: I want to receive a property with a specific type in a function, not declare it.